# Can somebody explain the following xor property

Tags: algorithm, xor, bit

I a forum it is mentioned that given array of `n` numbers:

```
arr[0........n-1]
```

The following conditon holds, `^` is the `xor` operator `

```
f(l,r) = f(0,r) ^ f(0,l-1)
```

where `f(l,r) = arr[l]^arr[l+1]^........arr[r]`

I checked the above taking number of arrays and different values of `l` and `r` and **YES**, it is true. But I don't understand how?

Can somebody please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Write out the expansion for `f(0,r) ^ f(0,l-1)`, and then cancel terms.

Answer (score 5):

Use the simplest property of XOR

```
f(0,r) ^ f(0,l-1) = f(l,r)
=> (f(0,r) ^ f(0,l-1)) ^ f(0,l-1) =  f(0,l-1) ^ f(l,r)
=> f(0,r) = f(l,r) ^ f(0,l-1) [Since XOR is associative f(0,l-1) ^ f(0,l-1) = 0 and x ^ 0 = x]  
=> f(0,r) = (arr[0]^...arr[l-1])^(arr[l]^...^arr[r])
```

which is definition of `f(0,r)`.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers arr[0...r] can be seen as two parts arr[0...l-1], arr[1...r]
so f(0,r) = f(0,l-1) ^ f(l,r) , by treating the two parts separately.

In f(l,r) = f(0,r) ^ f(0,l-1)  the f(0,l-1) cancels with the f(0,l-1) in f(0,r) leaving f(l,r) behind.